# Narrowing down `unknown` to an enum

Tags: typescript, types

I am trying to narrow down a variable of type `unknown` to a string enum in TypeScript. Here is a simplified version:

```
enum Fruit {
  Apple = "Apple",
  Banana = "Banana",
}

function getFruitPrice(x: Fruit) { ... }


const fruit: unknown = ???;

if (typeof fruit !== 'string') throw new Error();
if (!Object.values(Fruit).includes(fruit as Fruit)) throw new Error();

const price = getFruitPrice(fruit); // ERROR: fruit is still of type `string`, not `Fruit`
```

However, the above code does not work. After the `Object.values(...).includes` line, `fruit` is still considered a `string` rather than a `Fruit`. How do I narrow down an unknown variable to an enum type?

Note: I am using TypeScript version `4.0.2`, I am unable to upgrade to a later version due to working in a legacy codebase.

Comment: One recommendation would be to create a type guard function here.

Comment: I have also tried using a guard function that returns `x is Fruit`, however that still doesn't work and it still has a `string` type afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there was something wrong with the type guard function you were using. This seems to work fine:

```js
enum Fruit {
  Apple = "Apple",
  Banana = "Banana",
}

function getFruitPrice(x: Fruit) {
  return 10
}

function argIsFruit(arg: any): arg is Fruit {
  // The as string[] assertion is needed here to stop tsc complaining that a value of type string is not assignable to parameter of type Fruit
  return (!!arg && typeof arg === 'string' && (Object.values(Fruit) as string[]).includes(arg))
}

const fruit: unknown = "Apple"

if (argIsFruit(fruit)) {
  // Inside this block, fruit is of type Fruit
  const price = getFruitPrice(fruit);
  console.log(price)
} else {
  // Here, fruit is of type unknown
  console.log(`${fruit} is not a fruit`)
}
```